# How to toggle states using scrollTop?

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have a function that when the user scrolls off of the top of the window, it changes the height of the header and the padding of the list items.  That part of the function is fine, but I am trying to get the header and list items to return to their original size when the user scrolls back to the top. Any ideas?

```
$(function(){
    var header = $('#header');
    var padding = $('#header ul li a');
    var headerPosTop = header.offset().top;
    var win = $(window);
    win.scroll(function(e){
        var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop >= headerPosTop){
            header.css({height:'60px'});
            padding.css({padding:'17px 12px'});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you need an `else {}` clause that will handle when the position is at the top. you then set your original styles. the cleaner way is to add or remove appropriate CSS class names to those elements so you don't have to remember individual property values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving the original padding and height on load and use an `else` statement to apply it

```
$(function(){
    var header = $('#header');
    var padding = $('#header ul li a');
    var headerPosTop = header.offset().top;
    var origHeight = header.height(), 
        origPadding = padding.css("padding");
    var win = $(window);
    win.scroll(function(e){
        var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop >= headerPosTop){
            header.css({height:'60px'});
            padding.css({padding:'17px 12px'});
        }
        else {
            header.css(origHeight);
            padding.css(origPadding);
        }
    });
});
```

As Derek mentioned in the comments toggling a class would usually be a better practice than this because it is easier to write, maintain, and likely performs better

```
/* CSS */
heightClass { height:60px; }
paddingClass { padding: 17px 12px; }

/* JS */
$(function(){
    var header = $('#header');
    var padding = $('#header ul li a');
    var headerPosTop = header.offset().top;
    var win = $(window);
    win.scroll(function(e){
        var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop >= headerPosTop){
            header.addClass("heightClass");
            padding.addClass("paddingClass");
        }
        else {
            header.removeClass("heightClass");
            padding.removeClass("paddingClass");
        }
    });
});
```